# Python error while installing using homebrew

Tags: python, homebrew

Hi I installed python using "homebrew install python". 
A script which was already running started throwing below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestConnection.py", line 1, in <module>
    from TextUpdater import TextUpdater
  File "/Users/gepaul/code/external-tools/tools/Scripts/TextUpdater.py", line 1, in <module>
    from GSHelper import GSHelper
  File "/Users/gepaul/code/external-tools/tools/Scripts/GSHelper.py", line 2, in <module>
    import gspread
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gspread/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .client import Client, login, authorize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .httpsession import HTTPSession, HTTPError
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 16, in <module>
    from http import client
ImportError: cannot import name client
```

Any Idea why this happened?
Python version is Python 2.7.6

Comment: Homebrew probably changed the default python. if you run `which python` what do you get

Comment: /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: sys.path is different between whichever python you were using and Homebrew's python and so it can't find the same modules. You can add those paths back to sys.path using .pth files or by setting PYTHONPATH. The documentation for sys.path is here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.path#sys.path

Comment: Seems like installing homebrew installed some python 3 libraries in your python 2 installation , `http.client` is completely new in Python 3 , it was originally `httplib` in python 2 .